# Site stopped working after adding custom theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

I created custom theme ( having only theme.xml,regisration.php file and medial/preview.jpg ).

Logged in to admin panel and went to **Conetnt->Design->Configurations** so i could change the theme to my custom theme. but it shwoing me loadder file and no recored is showing. So i flushed the cache and now my frontend is not loading. Admin is working fine but theme sections is also not working.

I am working in default mode and my magento version is 2.2.3. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you check if there is any exception / error in var/log folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you should check if your code is valid, and there is not any php , xml typo error.

Best approach is copy theme.xml, registartion.php file from vendor/magento/theme-luma-frontend folder and add these in your theme. ( you can delete  part from theme.xml file if you have not any media/preview.jpg file.

If your theme is fine and there is not any code / typo error. Then go to your magento2 database and find table named **theme** ([Theme table](https://prnt.sc/l0g0vi)). Delete your custom theme record where theme_path = 'YourPackage/themename'

After that flush cache and load the site , hope it will be working.

( I had faced similar issue and in my case i had added custom theme and right after that flushed cache and changed deploy:mode to developer and it had crashed the site. Still trying to understand why did that happened)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes I had copied files from default luma theme. But I havn't tried theme table. I will check and update you.

Comment: It worked.!! deleting my theme record worked for me. deleted the record, re-index and then flushed cache. Thanks